# Scala unexpectedly compiles a file, are there implicit conversions at work?

Tags: scala, scala-implicits

I am trying to figure out why the classes below compile without error in Scala.
I would expect the `createTestClass` method in the `DoTest` class to fail with a typing error because it tries to supply the implicit parameter which has type `TypeClass[A]`, but instead of such an instance, it provides a lambda with type `A => String`.

Is there some implicit conversion at work here? How would I go about figuring out what's going on?

```
object Test {

  trait TypeClass[A] {
    def asString(a: A): String
  }

  object TypeClass {
    def apply[A: TypeClass]: TypeClass[A] = implicitly[TypeClass[A]]
  }

  case class TestClass[A: TypeClass](foo: Option[A] = None)

  object TestClass {
    def apply[A: TypeClass]: TestClass[A] = TestClass[A]()
  }

}

object DoTest {
  import Test.TestClass

  def createTestClass[A]: TestClass[A] =
    TestClass.apply[A]((_: A) => "test")

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala 2.12 introduced a new feature: [lambda syntax for SAM (Single Abstract Method) types](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types). That's simply what you're seeing here.